# How do I add additional variables so that I can set and switch each variable instead of having one $network command that controls all the variables?

Tags: php, html

Sorry if the title doesn't make any sense, I tried my best wording it. I'm trying, as the title suggests, to add additional variables to my php file for my 4 social media icons but I don't know what commands to use or how to code it. I tried looking it up on google and on here but I don't even know what words to look up, I'm relativly new to css,html,php/ Can anyone help, if you would like to see the icons you can go to my website http://boasish.com.

Here is what the $network command that is currently in my php file that controls the 4 social media icons.

```
foreach ($this->buttons as $network => $options) {
    if ($this->options['show'][$network]) {
        /*** Apply Shortcodes */
        $shortcodes = array(
            '[site_name]',
            '[permalink]',
            '[post_title]',
            '[post_image_url]',
            '[title_encode]'
            );
        $shortcode_values = array(
            $site_name,
            $permalink,
            $post_title,
            $post_image_url,
            $title_encode
            );
        $widget = str_replace($shortcodes,$shortcode_values,$options['widget']);

        $to_return .= '
    <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">
        <a href="#" class="icon icon-' . $network . '"><span>' . $options['name'] . '</span></a>
        <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
        </div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want four variables, each containing the `HTML` for a specific media button?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you wanted to keep your `$to_return` variable to keep your site working.

```
$media_buttons_html = array();
foreach ($this->buttons as $network => $options) {
    //All of your other code above
    $html = '<div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">  
                                 <a href="#" class="icon icon-' . $network . '">
                                     <span>' . $options['name'] . '</span>
                                 </a>
                                 <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
                             </div>';

    $to_return .= $html;
    $media_buttons_html[] = $html;
}
```

Something like this should work. You can access the buttons in the `array` with index `0` to `3`. Something like this:

```
$button_facebook = $media_buttons_html[0];
$button_instagram = $media_buttons_html[1];
$button_twitter = $media_buttons_html[2];
$button_googleplus = $media_buttons_html[3];
```

Hope that clears things up for you.

**Edit**
Make your foreach loop the original one again (the one you originally placed), and place this underneath there, or somewhere where you think it'll fit nicely. (You may need/want to place the function on the bottom of the file).

```
$media_buttons_html = create_media_buttons();

function create_media_buttons(){
    $links = array(){
        'facebook' => 'somefacebooklink',
        'instagram' => 'someinstagramlink',
        'twitter' => 'sometwitterlink',
        'gplus' => 'somegpluslink',
    }

    $media_buttons_html = array();
    foreach($links as $key => $link){
        $media_buttons_html[$key] = '<div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">  
                                         <a href="'. $link .'" class="icon icon-' . $network . '">
                                              <span>' . $options['name'] . '</span>
                                         </a>
                                         <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
                                     </div>';
    }

    return $media_buttons_html;
}
```

You can then use `$media_buttons_html` in the following way:

```
$facebook_button = $media_buttons_html['facebook'];
```

Comment: Ok that worked I think, thank you. This may sound stupid but how do I add a link to `$button_facebook = $media_buttons_html[0];` for example.

Comment: @k5432 Well, that depends. What kind of link do you want in there? What do you exactly intend to do with the variable? I might be able to give you a better solution then.

Comment: I'm looking to add a share link to each one of the buttons/icons. Also I just noticed there is two twitter icons now.

Comment: @k5432 Make sure you're only doing one loop (so not the loop you posted, and then after that the loop that I posted). What do you mean by sharelink? If those buttons on your website have those, the ones in the array should have them as well.

Comment: By share link I mean this https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=&original_referer= The # in $network tag is applied to all the media buttons `<a href="#"` points them to http://boasish.com/#/. I'm trying to give each icon there own link. So for twitter I want to add `<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=&original_referer="` Instead of the default `<a href="#"`.

Comment: @k5432 First; I think I see you're developing on your love website. I would advice you to not do that. If you mess something up on your website it could be a hassle to get it working again. In the meantime your website won't work (partly or not). Other than that it does seem weird that there is no link connected to those buttons. Let me write something up.

Comment: So I tried adding it and it didn't work. I get a blank white page when I add it so not sure where to go from here. I may need to try another way of doing this.

Comment: @k5432 At this point I'd advise you to let someone who knows what they're doing take care of it. You could do some damage to your website if you try to handle it yourself without any knowledge about the subject. What you're trying to do is not really complicated, but I'm not sure how much experience you have to actually implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Bono had:

I think it would be more intuitive (and less remembering later) to use an associative array with the network name as a key, instead of a simple array. 3 months later, I wont remember that `$media_buttons_html[0];` == facebooks' code.

Plus, you could automate the variables a little more in case you wanted to add more later.

```
$media_buttons_html = array();
foreach ($this->buttons as $network => $options) {
    //All of your other code above
    $html = '<div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">  
                             <a href="#" class="icon icon-' . $network . '">
                                 <span>' . $options['name'] . '</span>
                             </a>
                             <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
                         </div>';

$to_return .= $html;
$media_buttons_html[$network] = $html;
${'button_'.$network} = $html
}
```

So that now `$media_buttons_html` looks like `$media_buttons_html['facebook']`.
In addition to that, you can use `$button_facebook` without you explicitly setting it afterwards.

If you add anymore `$network`s later, there are no additional variables to make.